# I'm trying to figue out why I'm getting a NullPointerException when my app transitions from onCreate to onResume

Tags: android, onresume

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    BluetoothManager btManager = new BluetoothManager(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if (!btManager.isEnabled()) {
        btManager.requestBluetoothEnable();
        discoveryStarted = false;

    } else {
        if (btManager.isDeviceSetNullOrEmpty()) {
            btManager.startDiscovery();
            discoveryStarted = true;
        }

    }

}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    if( btManager.isEnabled() && discoveryStarted == false ){
```

I get a NullPointer exception here even though I initialized my btManager class ( a wrapper around a few Bluetooth classes .

Comment: Post your logcat output.

Comment: I don't believe `BluetoothManager` is a class provided in the public SDK...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BluetoothManager btManager = new BluetoothManager(this);
```

is only declared locally in the onCreate.

Try putting `BlueToothManager btManager;` as a class-wide field (just below class declaration). Then, inside oncreate:

```
btManager = new BluetoothManager(this);
```

Then, see if you can access it without the nullpointer inside onResume!

Comment: His code wouldnt even compile because of this. But maybe thats the problem anyhow

Comment: Indeed, but seeing as we only see a portion of the code, I figured it would be best to post this suggestion either way. We'll see, I guess!

Comment: DEAR GOD! What a mistake. I did have the btManager as a class-wide field but at some point created a local variable also. Programming tired. Thanks guys.

Comment: I'll excuse it in exchange for an upvote/correct! Happy programming.